# How to delete a read only folder in windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, directory

I have tried multiple options. I check properties and tried to uncheck read-only (but again it is changed back to read-only). I tried changing the permissions from command prompt and do `rm -rf` but still not able to delete the folder.

Is there any trickery by which we can delete it. I am not able to get which process is using it.

Comment: Perhaps you want to try this on http://www.serverfault.com ? I think you probably have to be an administrator and take ownership of the folder or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior occurs because the folder is customized. You can customize a folder by clicking Customize this folder on the View menu. Many programs also customize folders (for example, the Fonts folder comes with a customization as part of the standard system configuration).

**[Following](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256614)**  steps will tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, **[back up](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)** the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.

- Start Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).
- Locate the following registry key:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer
- On the Edit menu, point to New, click DWORD Value, and then type the following registry value name:
  UseSystemForSystemFolders
- Right-click the new value, and then click Modify.
- Type 1, and then click OK.
- Quit Registry Editor.
- After you make this change to the registry, you must change the Read-Only attribute for all affected folders by using the attrib command at a command prompt (Command.com or Cmd.exe). Type attrib /? at the command prompt to view the syntax for the attrib command. For example, to change the Read-Only attribute to System for the C:\Test folder, use the following command:
  attrib -r +s c:\test